# Running two python scripts at the same time and kill them simultaneously with key input

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

What I want to do is run two python scripts simultaneously and then kill them both on command. I'm not very well versed in bash scripting but here is what I have so far in the bash script:

```
python3 appcode.py &
python3 igc.py &
```

When I run this however, the bash script keeps restarting when I kill the process with its PID. I then rewrote it to have an exit command after those scripts are run which stops the bash, but the scripts continue to run in the background.

How would I write this so that when I enter something like ctrl-c or another key input in the terminal that it was started in, both python scripts and the bash script will all end simultaneously? Thank you!

**Edit:**

I would have one import the other and run it that way, however I am using Pyautogui and PyQt5 and when I import the pyautogui script into the script that has PyQt5, I am met with this error:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x1894380) is not the object's thread (0x2042850).
Cannot move to target thread (0x1894380)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/connor/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to have one python script that imports both files and starts the functionality using multiprocessing or a similar mechanism. "Killing" is really just a last-resort method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can start them together doing

```
python3 appcode.py & python3 igc.py
```

Ctrl+c will kill both

Comment: I assume that Ctrl+c only kills the first process.